# How can I show a button on a DataGrid only when the mouse is over the row?

Tags: material-design-in-xaml

I have a DataGrid where I've put a column with a button. I'd want that the button appears only when the mouse is over the row, like it happens in Windows Mail program. How can I do this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPacD.png)

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
                ...

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIconButton}"
                                ToolTip="Delete" >
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="DeleteOutline" />
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```